# Does traffic skip my AWS ELB if I don't specify its security group in my EB environment's inbound rules?

Tags: security, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-elb

I have an AWS Elastic Beanstalk environment that is created with an Elastic Load Balancer, and which specifies the default ELB security group ("ELB created security group used when no security group is specified during ELB creation") as the source for inbound HTTP.

If I replace this default ELB security group as the source for my environment's security group's inbound rules with a port range does traffic

- still come through the ELB and is it
- still filtered by the ELB's security group's rules

or does traffic then "skip" the ELB (or at least it's security group) and come directly to my instances?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're confusing the concept of network routing with firewall rules.  The security groups will not effect where traffic is directed.

**Networking routing:**

- DNS Settings will direct traffic to your ELB.
- ELB configuration will funnel traffic it receives to the EC2 instances registered with it.

**Security Groups:**

- Your ELB & EC2 instances have security groups assigned to them.  Regardless of what the network routing rules that directed the traffic to there, the firewall will ask the question "Do I allow traffic from a.b.c.d/R over port X?"

So to answer your question:

Yes, you can update the security group of your EB environment to allow traffic from an ELB.  Doing so will not impact where that ELB will direct traffic.

Yes, if the network routing you have in place sends traffic first to an ELB and then to an EC2 instance, the traffic must meet the requirements of the ELB's security group & the EC2 instance's security group.  If your instances are in a private subnet, the ELB cannot be skipped when starting from an external endpoint.  If the EC2 instances are in a public subnet, a user could access your instance directly if your firewall rules allow it.

However, I highly suspect that you're thinking something is going to happen here that won't.  I urge you to read up networking.  A good starting spot would be the VPC documentation (http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/VPC_Scenarios.html).  Work through the scenarios to understand what the role of each component is.

Comment: Yes, I'm at least conflating, if not confusing. Or, more accurately, avoiding: I'm taking whatever routing is provided by default by EB for load balanced environments as given, and am not changing it (which is why the linked scenarios were pretty unhelpful to me).

Comment: I think the piece I'm missing here is, *given the default routing in a load balanced EB environment*, how does this work? It seems that in that case all traffic comes through the ELB, so that my environment SG *must* have a rule that allows from an SG assigned to the ELB (I don't think health check URLs even work otherwise). If that's right, then it seems the [rules in SG's assigned to the ELB are the appropriate place to be filtering](http://stackoverflow.com/q/28459626/656912) access to my environments .

Comment: Actually, it's more confusing than that. It seems that the environments are public, so that their SGs do either need to be limited to allowing from the ELB SG or repeat (or provide their own limits on sources); but SSH rules don't matter at all. I can remove SSH rules everywhere (none on the ELB SG, none on my EB environment's SGs), and I can still SSH to my instances.

Comment: If you remove ssh rules from your security group, you will not be able to ssh to the instance.  If your instances are in a public subnet, they could be publicly accessible.  Your security group will need to deny undesirable traffic.  You'll need to analyze the incoming routes to your instance and assess if traffic is blocked appropriately.   To your original question, traffic does not skip the elb unless someone directly accesses a vm by ip address.

Comment: Starting from the basic EB configuration (using `eb clone` to create an environment), if I remove the SSH rule from my security group, I can SSH.

Comment: I think a lot of the confusion (from me) is about levels of abstraction (and the way the docs handle it). I'm coming to AWS with *zero* networking understanding (and no desire to mess with it), but I do want to take advantage of EB's (touted) features, apically simplification of app building and firewalls. So the only thing I'm touching (or looking at) is the SGs. But clearly there are things going on behind the scenes that need explaining, so if there's a simple map somewhere of where traffic goes in a default EB environment using an ELB, that would help to clear things up I think.

Comment: Cutting through all this though (and setting aside the odd SSH behavior), it seems like the only reliable way to get control of web traffic through the ELB to my EB environment's instances is to (1) create a new SG with the restrictions I want (2) assign that to the ELB (instead of the default SG) and (3) give it as only source for HTTP in my EB's SG. As near as I can tell, everything then works (though I'm left unsure — and a bit frustrated, since *none* of that clones when I clone an environment).